# Significato di "nel suo degli altri"

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Adesso mi viene freddo nel filo della schiena se penso che alla mira che eravamo non ci voleva piú che un soffio a perdere la terra e la casa e restare solo piú con le nostre braccia al mondo. E che se ci andava male del tutto, adesso Emilio dovrebbe morire **nel suo degli altri**.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "nel suo degli altri". Ho cercato alla voce "suo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione.

Comment: Secondo questo [articolo della rivista *Otto/Novecento*](https://books.google.es/books?id=0HNWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che%22&dq=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJn6PNyYLcAhVDEJoKHaN0CusQ6AEIEjAC) (rivista di critica e storia letteraria) il significato di "nel suo degli altri" è "nella terra altrui".

Comment: nice finding, but I think that this question is not much about the Italian language but more about Italian literature. The expression is not in any way idiomatic in Italian, it is just a personal usage of the writer with literary intent.

Comment: @Gio: Non ne sono sicura: Fenoglio in questo romanzo usa moltissime espressioni e vocaboli di origine dialettale/regionale.

Comment: @Gio: Ho trovato questa stessa espressione su [questo sito web](https://marcogiacosa.wordpress.com/2017/11/06/cane-bau/). L'autore è di Torino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho trovato conferma della supposizione di @Charo in questa pubblicazione di [Istituto Italiano Edizioni Atlas](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/0fbdd674-08db-46ab-a7ad-02c32c93e47c):

> 14. ***nel suo degli altri***: nella proprietà altrui (perché la famiglia
>       non possiede più una casa propria); è quasi un ossimoro,
>       che ben esprime il senso di una radicale privazione.

Il significato nel contesto da te citato è, appunto, nella terra o proprietà altrui.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo questo [articolo della rivista *Otto/Novecento*](https://books.google.es/books?id=0HNWAAAAYAAJ&q=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che%22&dq=%22c%27%C3%A8+posto+che&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJn6PNyYLcAhVDEJoKHaN0CusQ6AEIEjAC), una  rivista di critica e storia letteraria, il significato di "nel suo degli altri" è "nella terra altrui". Penso che molto probabilmente  si tratti di un articolo su *La malora* di Beppe Fenoglio perché vengono spiegate altre espressioni che appaiono nel romanzo, ma, purtroppo, la visualizzazione snippet di Google Books non mi permette leggerlo.

Comment: Siccome non si è trovato niente di meglio, ho deciso di metterlo come risposta. Spero però in una risposta più completa.